# torophp class not found

Tags: php, url-routing, autoload

I am using MVC PHP framework and Torophp for routing

this is my public/index.php

```html
<?php

class HomeController {
    function get() {
        echo "hello world";
    }
}



require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
 ToroHook::add("404",  function() {
  echo "404 - Not Found";
 });

 Toro::serve(array(

     "/" => "HomeController";

));

?>
```

when i search hhtp://example.com/  it worked fine and showed hello world

but if i comment out the class HomeController from index.php and declare it in app/controllers/HomeController.php

```html
<?php

class HomeController {
    function get() {
        echo "hello world";
    }
}
```

it doesn't work it shows class not found or error 400 internal server error.

here is my composer.json file

```html
{
 "name": "namespace/app",
 "description": "This is just sample",
 "require": {
  "torophp/torophp": "dev-master", 
  "twig/twig": "2.0" 
 },
 "authors": [
  {
   "name": "ABC",
   "email": "abc@xyz.com"
  }

 ],
 "autoload":{
  "psr-4":{
   "Links\\Controllers\\":"app/controllers",
   "Links\\Models\\":"app/models"
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: This is a namespace/auto-loading issue, not related to MVC in any way.

Comment: ways to solve auto loading issue?

Comment: this is my autoload.php   <?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit1833e0959563f4a1e86aaf1db23b78ef::getLoader();

Comment: As  someone who has had to use Toro in the past, here is a free advice: don't use it.

Comment: What are the problems that you faced using Toro? i find it really easy for routing.Instead of it what do you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Composer generates an autoloader based on the [`autoload`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload) section you put in `composer.json`:

```
"autoload":{
    "psr-4":{
        "Links\\Controllers\\":"app/controllers",
        "Links\\Models\\":"app/models"
    }
}
```

It says that the classes in the namespace `Links\Controllers` can be found in files having the same name as the class (and the `.php` termination) in the `app/controllers` directory. Similar for the namespace `Links\Models`.

The main script:

```
Toro::serve(array(
     "/" => "HomeController";
));
```

tells the router to use the `HomeController` class to serve the requests for `/`.

Btw, the semicolon (`;`) after `"HomeController" is a syntax error; the code doesn't even start because it doesn't compile. There should be a comma  (`,`) there, not a semicolon.

Because the `HomeController` class was not declared yet, the autoloader is invoked to find it and it fails because it has no information about where to find the classes from the global namespace.

You have put the `HomeController` class in the `app/controllers/HomeController.php` file but this is not enough. The autoloader reads this file when the interpreter needs to use the class `Link\Controllers\HomeController` and this class was not already declared.

This doesn't happen in `app/controllers/HomeController.php`. This file declares the class `HomeController` that is not being placed in any namespace, therefore it belongs to the global namespace. In order to put it into the `Links\Controllers` namespace you have to put this declaration line before any other statement in `app/controllers/HomeController.php`:

```
namespace Links\Controllers;
```

Now you the name of the class is `Links\Controllers\HomeController`. Change the code that uses it to:

```
Toro::serve(array(
     '/' => 'Links\Controllers\HomeController',
));
```

and it should work.